# static inline vs inline static

Tags: c, static, inline, c99, function-declaration

I have noticed that both work, what is the correct way to use inline here?

```
static inline int getAreaIndex()
```

OR

```
inline static int getAreaIndex()
```

Plus, getAreaIndex contains a large loop. sometimes I call it only one and sometimes I call it through a loop, should I inline it? (it's 10 line tall)

Comment: For future reference, around here we strongly encourage asking only one question per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C standard (6.7 Declarations)

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
```

It means that you may specify declaration specifiers in any order.

So for example all shown below function declarations declare the same one function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int getAreaIndex( void );
inline static int getAreaIndex( void );
int static inline getAreaIndex( void );
static int inline getAreaIndex( void );
inline int static getAreaIndex( void )
{
    return  0;
}


int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

As for the inline function specifier then according to the C Standard (6.7.4 Function specifiers)

> 6 A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline
>   function. Making a ∗function an inline function suggests that calls to
>   the function be as fast as possible.138)**The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.**

and there is a footnote

> 139) For example, **an implementation might never perform inline
>   substitution**, or might only perform inline substitutions to calls in
>   the scope of an inline declaration

Pay attention to that you should specify as the function parameter `void`. Otherwise the compiler will decide that the number and types of arguments are deduced from a function call.

Comment: Thanks, may you help answer my second question too?

Comment: @smith_brown See my appended answer. It is the implementation that decides whether to make the function inline.

Comment: @smith_brown I am saying about the parameter. If you will not specify parameters then the compiler will try to deduce  the number and types of parameters when it encounters a function call that is error-probe.

Comment: I didn't understand that, what parameter are you referring to? could you add simple example to explain it?

Comment: @smith_brown Did you specify  parameters? No. There are an empty parentheses. So the compiler can say nothing about how many parameters the function actually have. It is only in C++ empty parentheses mean that the function has no parameters.

Comment: Actually I have parameters (removed them to keep the code clean). in general I shouldn't care about this parameters things right?

Comment: @smith_brown You are wrong. In such a case the program is potentially error-prone.

Comment: @smith_brown Why should you remove inline?

Comment: @smith_brown I do not understand what you are saying. How are parameters   connected with the function specifier inline?!

Comment: you said "In such a case the program is potentially error-prone" what do u refer to in in such a case?

Comment: @smith_brown We are  talking about parameters are not we? Please reread the comments.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the correct way to use inline here

Both `static inline` and `inline static` are allowed and they mean the same thing. `static inline` is preferred, because "storage class specifiers" like `static` are always supposed to come first in a declaration (see [C11 §6.11.5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5p1)).

> should I inline this function

To answer this question you will need to benchmark your program both ways and find out which is faster.

Comment: I heard that inline will not cause a damage (or faster or nothing) but since I'm not using this function only inside loop I don't know if it's worth it

Comment: Inlining definitely can make your program slower.  The most common reason is if it makes your program big enough that it no longer fits in the instruction cache.

Comment: "static inline is preferred style." -- according to what source?

Comment: @JasonS According to the C standard itself, in fact. N1570 §[6.11.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5p1): "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."

Comment: mention that in your answer, then.

Comment: "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature." That's a really weak statement, and it's still present in N2731 http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2731.pdf I get why something like `static int foo()` would be preferred over `int static foo()` but why would `inline static` vs `static inline` matter?

Answer (score 2):

They are functionally equivalent at the moment, but `static inline` is the correct way to write C. This is because of C17 having made other styles obsolete and bad practice:

> 6.11.5 Storage-class specifier
>
> The placement of a storage-class speciﬁer other than at the beginning of the declaration speciﬁers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

`static` being a "storage class specifier".

Comment: it doesn't say "obsolete", it says "obsolescent" meaning "that they may be considered for withdrawal in future revisions of this International Standard". And there's no justification for this; to be honest I don't see why this is here, aside to try to discourage `int static foo()` instead of `static int foo()`. I wish they would say that the type-specifier and type-qualifier should be closer to the object name, or at least that storage-class-specifier and function-specifier were of equivalent importance.

Answer (score 1):

Function specifiers, such as `inline`, and storage class specifiers, such as `static`, may appear in any order as part of a function declaration.

So both examples above mean exactly the same thing.

As for whether you should `inline`, the details of exactly what `inline` does implementation defined.  So you should look up the documentation of your compiler to see.

Comment: Thanks may you answer my second question too?

Answer (score 1):

> should I inline it?

Inline is just a hint for the compiler and the compiler is free to disregard it if it would be too detrimental for performance.

Also, for locally defined functions (in the same .c file/translation unit), the compiler can freely decide to inline a function, even if it was not marked as such.

In most cases, for `static` function not defined in headers, I believe it is preferred not to specify `inline`, and let the compiler inline the function as it sees fit, according to the optimization options you are providing it (`-O<n>`, `-Ofast`, `-Osize`).